# How do I change the sans serif font in my document?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I am writing a document in Latex using the class scrbook and I have changed the main font to Palladio.  The problem is that now I don't like the default sans serif font, and I would like to change it. How can I achieve this? I want to change only the sans serif font, I have tried with something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside, DIV=8]{scrbook}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{venturis}
\linespread{1.05}         % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But it doesn't work, 'defaultsans' seems to be an unknown option for "venturis" and I get an error (and the whole document in sans serif, which I do not want). I actually would like to try both Venturis and Epigraphica. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

(Also, if you have suggestion on which sans serif matches best with Palladio...)

Answer (score 8):

The `venturis` package sets both the serif and sans serif fonts to the corresponding Venturis varieties. It has no option for just enabling Venturis Sans for `\sffamily`.

But you might be able to do it, by changing the loading order; indeed it works. Not that I consider this to be a good choice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside, DIV=8]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{venturis}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\linespread{1.05}         % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)%

\begin{document}

This is in ``MathPaZo''

\textsf{This is in Venturis Sans}

X\textsf{X}a\textsf{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>If the next question is how to remove the annoying informational messages about `` Font shape T1/yv1/mc/n has incorrect series value `mc' ``, sorry: unless the package maintainer fixes it, there's little you can do.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this works! You don't consider this to be a good choice because the code is inelegant or because you find it typographically unpleasing?

Comment: @FedericoR. Not the best combination, in my opinion, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: What whould be a better one in your opinion?

Comment: A more traditional combination is Palatino + Helvetica

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with `fontspec` for `xelatex` and `lualatex` provided you have installed the relevant OTF versions of the fonts (TeX Gyre family from [here](https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/index_html) and Venturis from [here](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/tugfonts.htm)).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside, DIV=8]{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setsansfont{VenturisSans ADF}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\linespread{1.05}         % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)%

\begin{document}

\section{This title is set in Venturis}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is in \TeX\ Gyre Pagella, with some maths $e=mc^2$.
\item \textsf{This is in Venturis Sans}
\item X\textsf{X}a\textsf{a}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

### Notes

- `unicode-math` calls `fontspec` automatically, to give you the three font setting commands.
- Venturis is a little smaller than the Palatino-look-a-like, so I have used the `fontspec` option `[Scale=MatchLowercase]` to increase the *x*-height so that the sans font matches the main font.
- It is possible that `mathpazo` provides some more clever settings, which you do not get from `unicode-math`, but I have never discovered any.
- This approach forces you to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

If you wanted the more "traditional" combination, you could install an OTF version of a Helvetica-look-a-like, such as TeX Gyre Heros, and change the `setsansfont` line

```
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

to get this

[image]